# Scrabble cheater: scoring wildcard characters to zero in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python world, and I made a code of scrabble finder with two wildcards (* and ?) in it. When scoring the word, I would like to score wildcard letters to zero, but it looks like it doesn't work. I'm wondering what is missing here.

When you look into the line after "# Add score and valid word to the empty list", I tried to code if a letter in the word is not in the rack, I removed the letter so that I can only score other characters that are not coming from wildcards and matches with the letter in the rack. For example, if I have B* in my rack and the word is BO, I would like to remove O and only score B so that I can score wildcard to zero.

But the result is not what I expected.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("no rack error.")
    exit(1)

rack = sys.argv[1]
rack_low = rack.lower()

# Turn the words in the sowpods.txt file into a Python list.
with open("sowpods.txt","r") as infile:
    raw_input = infile.readlines()
    data = [datum.strip('\n') for datum in raw_input]

# Find all of the valid sowpods words that can be made
# up of the letters in the rack.
valid_words = []

# Call each word in the sowpods.txt
for word in data:
    # Change word to lowercase not to fail due to case.
    word_low = word.lower()
    candidate = True
    rack_letters = list(rack_low)
    # Iterate each letter in the word and check if the letter is in the
    # Scrabble rack. If used once in the rack, remove the letter from the rack.
    # If there's no letter in the rack, skip the letter.
    for letter in word_low:
        if letter in rack_letters:
            rack_letters.remove(letter)
        elif '*' in rack_letters:
            rack_letters.remove('*')
        elif '?' in rack_letters:
            rack_letters.remove('?')
        else:
            candidate = False
    if candidate == True:
        # Add score and valid word to the empty list 
        total = 0
        for letter in word_low:
            if letter not in rack_letters:
                word_strip = word_low.strip(letter)
                for letter in word_strip:
                    total += scores[letter]

        valid_words.append([total, word_low])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go a slightly different route with my answer and hopefully speed the overall process up.  We're going to import another function from the standard library -- permutations -- and then find possible results by trimming the total possible word list by the length of the rack (or, whatever argument is passed).

I've commented accordingly.

```
import sys
from itertools import permutations # So we can get our permutations from all the letters.

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("no rack error.")
    exit(1)

rack = sys.argv[1]
rack_low = rack.lower()


# Turn the words in the sowpods.txt file into a Python list.
txt_path = r'C:\\\\\sowpods.txt'
with open(txt_path,'r') as infile:
    raw_input = infile.readlines()
    # Added .lower() here.
    data = [i.strip('\n').lower() for i in raw_input]

## Sample rack of 7 letters with wildcard character.
sample_rack = 'jrnyoj?'

# Remove any non-alphabetic characters (i.e. - wildcards)
# We're using the isalpha() method.
clean_rack = ''.join([i for i in sample_rack if i.isalpha()])

# Trim word list to the letter count in the rack.
# (You can skip this part, but it might make producing results a little quicker.)
trimmed_data = [i for i in data if len(i) <= len(clean_rack)]


# Create all permutations from the letters in the rack
# We'll iterate over a count from 2 to the length of the rack
# so that we get all relevant permutations.
all_permutations = list()
for i in range(2, len(clean_rack) + 1):
    all_permutations.extend(list(map(''.join, permutations(clean_rack, i))))


# We'll use set().intersection() to help speed the discovery process.
valid_words = list(set(all_permutations).intersection(set(trimmed_data)))


# Print sorted list of results to check.
print(f'Valid words for a rack containing letters \'{sample_rack}\' are:\n\t* ' + '\n\t* '.join(sorted(valid_words)))
```

Our output would be the following:

```
Valid words for a rack containing letters 'jrnyoj?' are:
    * jo
    * jor
    * joy
    * no
    * nor
    * noy
    * ny
    * on
    * ony
    * or
    * oy
    * yo
    * yon
```

If you want to verify that the results are actually in the sowpods.txt file, you can just index the sowpods.txt list by where the word you want to look up is indexed:

```
trimmed_data[trimmed_data.index('jor')]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are totalling the scores you are using the words from the wordlist and not the inputted words:

```
total=0
for letter in word_low:
    ...
```

Rather, this should be:

```
total=0
for letter in rack_low:
    ...
```

Also, You do not need to loop and remove the letters with strip at the end.
you can just have:

```
total = 0
for letter in rack_low:
    if letter not in rack_letters:
        try:
            total += scores[letter]
        except KeyError: # If letter is * or ? then a KeyError occurs
            pass

valid_words.append([total, word_low])
```